# T-SQL: Remove 1 row out of 2 rows where the value of 1 column is double that of the second

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given the following 2 rows of data:-

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
33 10298 11588 4474.32
33 10298 11588 2237.16
```

How do I go about writing a T-SQL query which will remove only the first data row where ColumnsA - C are the same and the value in ColumnD is double that of the second data row.

It doesn't have to particularly performant as I am only removing approximately 500 rows.

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines should work:

```
DELETE FROM t2
FROM table t1
       inner join
     table t2
       on
          t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA and
          t1.ColumnB = t2.ColumnB and
          t1.ColumnC = t2.ColumnC and
          t1.ColumnD * 2 = t2.ColumnD
```

This assumes that if you have 3 rows where their ratios between columnD values are 1 : 2 : 4, you want to delete both the 2 and 4 rows. If that's not the case, please consider such a situation and let me know what should happen there.

[`DELETE` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)

---

Complete script:

```
create table T (A int,B int, C int, D int)
insert into T(A,B,C,D)
values (1,2,3,4),(1,2,3,8)

delete from t2
from t t1
    inner join
     t t2
        on
            t1.A = t2.A and t1.B = t2.B and t1.C = t2.C and t1.D * 2 = t2.D

select * from T
```

Result:

```
A           B           C           D
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           3           4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
delete from YourTable
from YourTable t1
where exists (select 1 from YourTable t2 where t1.ColumnA=t2.ColumnA and t1.ColumnB=t2.ColumnB and t1.ColumnC=t2.ColumnC and t1.ColumnD=t2.ColumnD*2)
```

You can't use the same table two times in a join statement, if You want delete from that table. So use istead the join an exists statement or join a derived table.

Comment: I've just added a complete script to the bottom of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30662708/15498) that does what's expected, so I'm not sure what you mean by "You can't use the same table two times in a join statement"

Comment: Oh. I don't known, thant I can use an alias after 'delete from' .